# How to make order by a_datetime more important that datetime?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, case, sql-order-by

I am running an SQL query, and what it does is for a forum. First it joins questions to their answers, then checks if the post is sticky, in this case, it isn't, then groups by id (Not sure why this is necessary, I got this part from a website) and finally orders them. How I'd like them to be ordered, is first with date/time, then if someone replies, it will go to the top. For example:

```
Post: 2 Replies: 1 Last Post: 10:00PM First Post: 9:00PM
Post: 3 Replies: 0 Last Post: 9:30PM  First Post: 9:30PM
Post: 1 Replies: 0 Last Post: 8:00PM  First Post: 8:00PM
```

Where this is returning:

```
Post: 3 Replies: 0 Last Post: 9:30PM  First Post: 9:30PM
Post: 2 Replies: 1 Last Post: 10:00PM First Post: 9:00PM
Post: 1 Replies: 0 Last Post: 8:00PM  First Post: 8:00PM
```

And here is the actual query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_question
LEFT JOIN forum_answer ON ( forum_question.id = forum_answer.question_id ) 
WHERE category =  '7'
AND  `sticky` =0
GROUP BY forum_question.id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN reply >0
THEN a_datetime
WHEN reply =0
THEN DATETIME
END DESC
```

Sample Data:

```
ID; Topic; Name; Detail; Datetime; Reply; Category; Sticky;
1; Post 1; Demo; Detail; 07/09/13, 9:00; 0; 7; 0;
2; Post 2; Demo; Detail; 07/09/13, 9:15; 0; 7; 0;
3; Post 3; Demo; Detail; 07/09/13, 9:30; 2; 7; 0;
4; Post 4; Demo; Detail; 07/09/13, 9:45; 0; 7; 0;

Question_ID; A_ID; A_Name; A_Detail; Datetime; 
3; 1; Demo1; Detail; 07/09/13, 9:31;
3; 2; Demo1; Detail; 07/09/13, 9:46;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM forum_question LEFT JOIN forum_answer 
    ON forum_question.id = forum_answer.question_id
 WHERE category =  '7'
   AND  `sticky` =0
 GROUP BY forum_question.id
 ORDER BY (reply = 0),
       CASE WHEN reply > 0 THEN a_datetime
            ELSE datetime
       END DESC
```

Comment: Actually, when I created a new topic, it didn't appear at the top, but instead, second to last! Any idea of how I can fix that?

Comment: @asbxzeeko You're quite welcome :) Can you post some sample data (just a few rows) for both tables to be able to test the query?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18679872/edit) your question and post sample data in it. In comments it's usually undecipherable.

Comment: Done, sorry it took so long

Comment: Please take a look at this **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e553e/1)** demo. The results seems to be correct for me. But maybe I'm missing something. Please tell me if it's not what you expected.

Comment: Well, I prtscrned the problem for you. (Sorry it took me so long to respond, and thanks for being soooo helpful <3 <3) This is it before adding a post: http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/251/9/1/error2_by_audreysaddleclub-d6lkefy.png And then after adding a new topic, I get: http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/251/2/e/error1_by_audreysaddleclub-d6lkeg6.png The new topic I added Neww Topic, appeared not at the top, but under posts with replies.